How to correctly bake Color Attributes to texture with multiple UVs?
I'm trying to combine two color attribute in texture:

and at this point character looks as it should:

but when I'm trying to bake it to texture with this settings:

I'm getting strange baked texture:

and difference in character's viewport:

As I found out the reason is selected UV, which will be used for baking. But I don't understand what to do when I have multiple UVs? Every UV will give me different result when in original shader I'm getting combination of all UVs (I suppose). How can I properly bake this attributes to texture

Select the UV map that should be used for baking in the Object Data Properties > UV Maps list or connect a UV Map node to the Image Texture node

@Blunder as I said "Every UV will give me different result when in original shader I'm getting combination of all UVs (I suppose)". So I can't get the proper result using just one UV.

You need to make sure:

The UV layout does not have overlaps.
When visualizing the texture — the UV layout it was baked for is plugged.

